# Linking logged in user to object data on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I'm new to using Parse.com and I'm trying to understand the general relationship between a logged in user and user-specific data.

I've figured out and understand how to create users and objects but I'm fuzzy on how to connect the two.

- Is it as simple as creating a user and then once their logged in, storing an object with their username as the key?
- Then when a user signs in successfully, you retrieve the object under their username key?

I just want to make sure I'm approaching this from the right angle, since I plan on having a lot of users and I also want the most secure approach.

I've read through the Parse.com documentation but can't seem to find the connection between the two. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add brief details about your environment/platform or SDK? Parse details differ a little bit between platforms.

Comment: @piojo This is for an iOS application on iPhone, using Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when the user submits any details it is recorded with their User ID? If so, then this code will work for you:

```
 ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
 //yourObjectID.put("User", user);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no user-specific data (all data is global with respect to the app ID you registered, as Parse is a database), but you can store data inside a ParseUser object. You can also give it access controls (an ACL), so only that user can read/write it. When the user signs in successfully, I don't believe it will be part of the ParseUser object yet, you need to fetch the data. (This is definitely true for object fields, but I'm not sure about simple fields like strings and ints. It deserves testing.)

There is a caveat to this. Depending on which SDK you're using, some of that information may be cached. In Unity 3D, for instance, the ParseUser object will retain all its data between program invocations (and indeed, will remain logged in).

Comment: So this can be done using a PFUser object? If so, I've tried something like this:

`var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser();
currentUser["message"] = "Hello World!";`

This didn't work so I'm wondering how to retrieve and save data to a logged in user. Or would I store a separate data class and possibly store each child key as a user name and set the ACL of the username key to the specific user?

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying above in that, when creating a new user, I could create a custom object key for storing data and then once logged in, edit and save the object. I guess this brings me to another question then.. is it ok to store larger data to the user say if it's another object with many key/value pairs?

Comment: First answer: according to the docs here, that code looks good. How did it fail? (https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users/iOS ). Second: If the data is not available in the PFUser object after login but you know it should exist, you could get the full object data by doing this query: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-retrieving/iOS

Comment: Third: Yes, it's fine. The object will be a pointer, anyway. The data won't be stored inside the PFUser, but will be available there (but since it's a separate PFObject, to ensure this extra data is available, you will need to use the `includeKey:` argument when you query the user).